# How do i execute an MSBuild Task in VS2010 Web Deployment Build Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, msbuild-task, web-deployment

We've recently upgraded from VS2008 -> VS2010 (and hence upgrading from Web Deployment Project to proper deployment project).

Obviously what's new in VS2010 web deployments is the introduction of Workflow as the build process template.

Previously, we used a MSBuild task in the WDP to execute the Yahoo YUI Javascript/CSS compression module to minify/compress javascript and css files.

Has anyone managed to accomplish this task with Visual Studio 2010?

I have seen the new "SquishIt" compressor created by Justin Etheridge, but its not ideal as it "squishes" on the fly (e.g on Application_Start - Global.ascx) - which means you still have to push out all the uncompressed files to your web server before squishing.

In the Workflow designer - i can see a toolbox item called "MSBuild" - just dont know how to use it to accomplish what i want.

Been searching high and wide, no-one seems to know how.

**EDIT**

After nearly 2 weeks, still no solution/answers. Surely someone has come across this problem? For now we've just been manually executing the MSBuild Task via VS Command Prompt post-build.

**EDIT**

Still nothing!!

Comment: Cool, im not alone then. =). For the time being we've just been manually running the DLL via MSbuild (Visual Studio Command Prompt). I hate it how the new VS "forces" you to learn Workflow for Web Deployments!

Comment: I ended up going with SquishIt because I couldn't find a better solution.

Comment: Yeah SquishIt is ok but as i said i dont like the idea of pushing out the assets to the live server and THEN squishing it. You should only need to push out what the live server would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using SquishIt.

Not ideal, because the files are "squished" at runtime. And IMO only the "assets" should be deployed to the server (e.g pre-minified).

But i have no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the UpgradeTemplate?

That one basically executes a MSBuild process and execute the targets file as if it were 2008

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please? Ie whats involved, how to get this going with CI, etc

Comment: You can choose from several templates in the build definition. When you choose the UpgradeTemplate, there is basically only one activity and that is to execute the targets file by MSBuild.

Thus you basically use the TFS 2008 way of running the build. You still can use the CI trigger and so on. 

There is one little caveat: the UpgradeTemplate uses MSBuild 4 instead of MSBuild 3.5 that was used by TFS2008. It probably won't hurt you, but I have heard people have had issues with that.